# Looking for a specific drill bit holder that reduces cam out

Tags: drill-bits

My father in law has a bit holder that doesn't actually allow the bit to turn unless enough pressure is applied. I've found that this helps to prevent cam out. I have not been able to find another one for sale.

Would anyone have an idea of what it's called and how I could find it ?

**EDIT:**

Unfortunately I don't have a picture of it.  It came with a Milwaukee brand drill he purchased years ago that came in a metal box.

The item in question looks long ( 4 inches about ) and thin ( pencil like ) with one end for the chuck and the other for the bit.  The cylinder is smooth with no other features or adjustments like I would expect with a torque adjustable style. For a while I always thought the drill was broken because I didn't know that I had to apply pressure to get the bit to spin.

Comment: Sounds like a clutch? They are more often used to limit torque so you don't strip the heads, but the standalone ones could have the side effect of requiring pressure; the old one I inherited does.

Comment: I learn something every day.  Cam out describes the driver bit spinning out of the slotted grooves in the head of a screw

Comment: @Ashlar, more info in this previous Q&A: [Why do I go through so many philips bits?](http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3045/why-do-i-go-through-so-many-philips-bits)

Comment: Was it a type of sleeve that would go over the screw itself? I had something like that - you put the sleeve over the bit, put the screw into the bit, then slide the sleeve down. You could hold the sleeve while the screw/bit turned inside it. Not sure if that helped reduce cam out or not, but it did help holding the screw in place, especially longer screws without pilot holes. (Hush you! I was young and we were doing general house work, not fine wood working!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally checked out the drill at my inlaws place and it turns out there is a special clutch inside of the drill. My mistake thinking it had something to do with the bit in the drill.

[image: Screw-Shooter Kit]

Answer (score 2):

Are you possibly talking about a drywall screw adapter?  These have a custom set that allows it to cam out when the screw is driven deep enough, and would probably not engage the screw if you didn't have it pushed on hard enough.

[image: drywall screw adapter]
<sup>([source](https://www.stanleytools.co.uk/product/187481))</sup>

Here's [another example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005BTM4HM) that has a spring on the back end that might fit your bill too.

[image: spring end]

Comment: Certainly not that.

Comment: @grbonk, hmm, no idea then.  Hopefully someone else has an idea.